Pdf.js renders donut chart with wrong colors when viewing in browser
We have a page of dynamically generated HTML that gets converted into a .PDF with C# and IronPDF. The original HTML and rendered .PDF look great, but when the PDF is viewed in the browser using Pdf.js, there is a donut chart that shows up entirely in pink. Here is the donut chart HTML that gets rendered (shown as a screen capture of the source, since the HTML itself is minified and not easily readable):

Here is the CSS for the donut chart (yes, I know the background-image attributes are duplicated; I'll fix that):
.page.overallCHSDetail .piewrapper {
    width: 14rem;
    height: 14rem;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.page.overallCHSDetail .pie {
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 14rem;
    height: 14rem;
}
.page.overallCHSDetail .piebase {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    width: 14rem;
    height: 14rem;
    z-index: 1;
}
.page.overallCHSDetail .pie1 {
    z-index: 5;
    background-image: conic-gradient(#FD752A 80%, #e0e0e0 80%, #e0e0e0 100%);
    transform: scale(1);
}
.page.overallCHSDetail .pie1inner {
    z-index: 6;
    transform: scale(.85);
    background-color: white;
}
.page.overallCHSDetail .pie2 {
    z-index: 10;
    background-image: conic-gradient(#255ed1 60%, #e0e0e0 60%, #e0e0e0 100%);
    transform: scale(0.81);
}
.page.overallCHSDetail .pie2inner {
    z-index: 11;
    transform: scale(.66);
    background-color: white;
}
.page.overallCHSDetail .pie3 {
    z-index: 15;
    background-image: conic-gradient(#5996e0 40%, #e0e0e0 40%, #e0e0e0 100%);
    transform: scale(0.62);
}
.page.overallCHSDetail .pie3inner {
    z-index: 16;
    transform: scale(.47);
    background-color: white;
}
.page.overallCHSDetail .pie4 {
    z-index: 20;
    background-image: conic-gradient(#8ab2e2 30%, #e0e0e0 30%, #e0e0e0 100%);
    transform: scale(0.43);
}
.page.overallCHSDetail .pie4inner {
    z-index: 21;
    transform: scale(.27);
    background-color: white;
}
.page.overallCHSDetail .pie5 {
    z-index: 25;
    background-image: conic-gradient(#a4b3c4 20%, #e0e0e0 20%, #e0e0e0 100%);
    transform: scale(0.23);
}
.page.overallCHSDetail .piecenter {
    z-index: 30;
    background-color: #fff;
    transform: scale(0.1);
}
.page.overallCHSDetail .pie .pie1label,
.page.overallCHSDetail .pie .pie2label,
.page.overallCHSDetail .pie .pie3label,
.page.overallCHSDetail .pie .pie4label,
.page.overallCHSDetail .pie .pie5label {
    color: white;
    font-size: .8rem;
    line-height: 150%;
    position: absolute;
    top: .25rem;
    left: calc(50% + 1.5rem);
    background-color: transparent;
}
.page.overallCHSDetail .pie .pie4label,
.page.overallCHSDetail .pie .pie5label {
    color: black;
}

Here is the donut chart as rendered in the browser from HTML (the PDF looks just like it when viewed in Acrobat):

Here is the donut chart when viewed in the browser with Pdf.js:

I'm trying to go through the source of Pdf.js for clues, but does anyone have any ideas what might be going wrong here? TIA!
